# I get error 32104 when when running an oracle db client written in c++ in visual studio

Tags: c++, oracle, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to build an oracle client in c++ using Visual Studio 2019.
The client is legacy code from 2010, so I am using the vs 2010 toolkit and oracle's instantclient 12.1 and 12.1 sdk.

When I debug the program, I get an error on the first oracle function call, outputing the sql error code 32104, which from oracle states:
[INS-32104] Specified Oracle Home user is not the owner of the specified Oracle Base

I am linking the instantclient sdk's include folder in my project properties, aswell as the static library (oraocci12d.lib), and I am adding the vc10 folder aswell as the root folder in the instantclient 12.1 path to my windows PATH variable, so that my program can find the oci.dll and oraocci12d.dll.

I have tried many variations of this, but no matter what I do, the program halts when it does its first oracle call, with the function createEnvironment() (any other call also halts the program).

The sqlerror code in my output is 32104, which from oracles documentation states:

[INS-32104] Specified Oracle Home user is not the owner of the specified Oracle Base

I do not have any ORACLE_HOME or any other oracle env variable set.

I found this, which seems like it is the same issue. He does the same thing is me in the solution, but for me it does not work: http://kaottt.blogspot.com/2009/06/oracle-10g-occi-11-vs2008.html

I am all out of ideas, any are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is your error a INS-32104 or an ORA-32104 which is `$ oerr ora 32104
32104, 00000, "cannot retrieve OCI error message"
// *Cause: Error message after an OCI call could not be retrieved.
// *Action:  This is an internal OCCI Error.  Please contact customer support.`

One reason error messages cannot be retrieved is that the necessary message library is not available on the client.  Is the one message the complete error stack?